# Cannot create secret key in flask; returns “name 'session' is not defined”

Tags: python, flask

Im attempting to create a website in flask. To do that, I need use sessions and therefore I am required to use a secret key. I did all of that, and yet it still returns a long error log with
`nameerror: name ‘session’ is not defined` at then end

I tried everything and moved the thing that sets the secret key everywhere, but it always had the same issue. Here is my code currently:

```
from flask import Flask
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

usernumber = 0

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    global usernumber
    session['usernumber'] = usernumber
    usernumber = usernumber + 1
    Usernumberstring = session['usernumber']
    return f"Welcome {Usernumberstring}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=True, debug=False, host="0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: You're not importing `session`?: `from flask import Flask, session`

Comment: If you will eventually deploy your app in a multi-process setup, your random initialization of the secret key won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not importing session;

`from flask import Flask, session`

Check more details about flask session here;

[https://pythonbasics.org/flask-sessions/#:~:text=Unlike%20cookies%2C%20Session%20(session),temporary%20directory%20on%20the%20server](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-sessions/#:%7E:text=Unlike%20cookies%2C%20Session%20(session),temporary%20directory%20on%20the%20server).